# How do I regex file name pattern XXXX_YYYYYY_filename.pdf

Tags: .net, regex

I need assistance with a RegEx pattern to validate file names in a specific format before upload. The format is:

> XXXX_YYYY_anyFileName.extension

- XXXX is a customer number which is alpha numeric with length 10.
- YYYY is a document number and must be numeric only.
- anyFileName would be a regular file name provided by the end-user.
- extension would be the default extension of the file being uploaded.

I was trying this as a test:

> ([A-Za-z0-9_]+)

but the following pattern xxxx.pdf is passed. I am not sure how to make the underscore a required entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
([A-Za-z0-9]{10})_([0-9]+)_(.+)\.(.+)
 ^                ^         ^     ^
 |                |         `-----` Any char, at least one
 |                | 
 |                ` A number must appear at least once
 ` only chars within "A-Za-z0-9" are allowed and must appear 10 times
```

In order to force that the whole string must match the regexp above, you might have to prefix it by `^` and postfix with `$`.

Try it here: http://regex101.com/r/qQ2dE4/5

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want special characters in your file name and extension you can use a regex like this:

```
^[A-Za-z\d]{10}_\d+_[A-Za-z\d]+\.[A-Za-z\d]+$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/xZ1jB4/2)**

[image]